# Isolating a unique value in one column, then copy down a value from another column to the other duplicate values?

Tags: excel, vba

I am struggling to figure out how to put this together and could use some help. I have a very large report I'm working on and doing any of this manually is simply not an option.

In the simplest explanation, I need to find instances where there are duplicate values in a column (Col J) and look at the first row that contains a duplicate. Then copy the value from another column (Col F) and paste it down into every other row that contains a duplicate in Col J.

To illustrate, if the report looks like this to start with:

```
+-----------------+--------------+
|  Col F          |  Col J       |
+-----------------+--------------+
| Value 1         |     1111     |
| Value 2         |     1111     |
| Value 3         |     2222     |
| Value 4         |     3333     |
| Value 5         |     1111     |
| Value 6         |     3333     |
| Value 7         |     3333     |
| Value 8         |     4444     |
| Value 9         |     4444     |
+-----------------+--------------+
```

I need it to look like this afterwards:

```
+-----------------+--------------+
|  Col F          |  Col J       |
+-----------------+--------------+
| Value 1         |     1111     |
| Value 1         |     1111     |
| Value 3         |     2222     |
| Value 4         |     3333     |
| Value 1         |     1111     |
| Value 4         |     3333     |
| Value 4         |     3333     |
| Value 8         |     4444     |
| Value 8         |     4444     |
+-----------------+--------------+
```

Any advice?

Comment: You can just use INDEX/MATCH in a new column: `=INDEX(F:F,MATCH(J1,J:J,0))`.

Answer (score 1):

To do in place, use a dictionary:

```
Sub rplc()
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With Worksheets("Sheet5") 'Change to your sheet name
        Dim lstrow As Long
        lstrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row

        Dim i As Long
        For i = 2 To lstrow
            If dict.exists(.Cells(i, 10).Value) Then
                .Cells(i, 6).Value = dict(.Cells(i, 10).Value)
            Else
                dict.Add .Cells(i, 10).Value, .Cells(i, 6).Value
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```